How do I bundle a service worker in Next.js?
I'm following this Firebase guide on setting up a service worker to intercept and modify fetch() requests. Currently, my implementation produces the error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at service-worker.js:1:1)

I suspect it's is related to this note in the guide

Make sure that the service worker is bundled so that it will still work after the browser has been closed.

This topic is new to me, and I'm unsure how to go about it. I'm using Next.js and  all I found in their docs was this.

Here's my service worker
// public/service-worker.js

import { auth } from "@/firebase/firebase"
import { getIdToken, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth"

// Firebase docs use "activate" not "install"
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  console.log("Installing...")
})

...


I'm installing it from a signup route, like this
// src/app/signup/SignUpForm.js

"use client"

export function SignUpForm() {
  useEffect(() => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', { scope: '/' })
    }
  }, [])
  ...
}


How do I resolve this error?

In the public folder the files are not compiled, you must have a manual compiler. I don't know if next.js has a plugin or not, but when I work with vite I usually write the plugin myself using esbuild
